# Inserting a prayer for someone with a mental illness in refueinu

Tags: tefilla, psych-mentalhealth

The [Mishna Brurah 116 s.k. 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.116.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) rules like the opinion that one may insert a prayer for the recovery of a sick person in the bracha of *refaeinu* during the Amidah (as opposed to the opinion that one must rather include such prayer in *shema koleinu*). Are there any sources that discuss if this includes praying for someone who has a mental illness? Would it depend on the severity or type of mental illness?